# click handler not called in angular custom directive while using ng-repaet

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have created a directive in angular, the template of the directive uses ng-repeat and inside the template there is a button which is having a click handler assigned to it using ng-click.

```
.directive('webEvent',function(){
 return{
    restrict:'E',
    replace: true,
    scope: {
        events: "="
    },
    template:"<div class='row' ng-repeat='event in events'>"+
                "<div class='col-md-8'>"+
                    "<p class='evTitle'>{{event.eventName}} @ {{event.eventPlace}} on {{event.eventDate}}</p>"+
                    "<p class='evLength'>You have {{event.eventLength}} events scheduled on this date</p>"+
                "</div>"+
                "<div class='col-md-4'><button type='button' class='btn btn-success pull-right' ng-show='event.expressIntrest' ng-click='expressIntrestClick($index)'>Express Intrest</button></div>"+
              "</div>",
    link:function(scope, elem, attrs){

         scope.expressIntrestClick=function(index){
         console.log("hello");
       }


        }
     }
```

});

The problem I am facing is the click handler for the button is not getting called.

When I created a similar directive without the ng-repeat the click handler is getting called. I have created plunks for both the directive. **What should I do so that the click handler gets invoked while using ng-repeat?**

[directive without ng-repeat](https://plnkr.co/edit/UITnFy?p=preview)

[directive with ng-repeat](https://plnkr.co/edit/Dt3kIF?p=preview)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the template should contain one **root** element.

When you use the `ng-repeat` in the template, it turns out that you do not **root** element.

See fixed [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/7LHQ9IxE8B7b5vXoIIel?p=preview).

Fixed template of directive:

```
 template: "<div><div class='row' ng-repeat='event in events'>" +
  "<div class='col-md-8'>" +
  "<p class='evTitle'>{{event.eventName}} @ {{event.eventPlace}} on {{event.eventDate}}</p>" +
  "<p class='evLength'>You have {{event.eventLength}} events scheduled on this date</p>" +
  "</div>" +
  "<div class='col-md-4'><button type='button' class='btn btn-success pull-right' ng-show='event.expressIntrest' ng-click='goit(event)'>Express Intrest</button></div>" +
  "</div></div>",
```

Comment: changing the template from `<div ng-repeat=""></div>` to  `<div><div ng-repeat=""></div></div>` did the trick. thanks